# best mysql table structure for INSERT only?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, insert, filesystems

I have a website on a shared host, where I expect a lot of visitors. I don't need a database for reading (everything presented on the pages is hardcoded in PHP) but I would like to store data that my users enter, so for writing only. In fact, I only store this to do a statistical analysis on it afterwards (on my local computer, after downloading it).

So my two questions:

1. Is MySQL a viable option for this? It is meant to run on shared hosting, with PHP/MySQL available, so I cannot really use much other fancy packages, but if e.g. writing to a file would be better for this purpose, that's possible too. As far as I understood, adding a line to a file is a relatively complex operation for huge files. On the other hand, 100+ users simultaneously connecting to a MySQL database is probably also a huge load, even if it's just for doing 1 cheap INSERT query.
2. If MySQL is a good option, how should the table best be configured? Currently I have one InnoDB table, with a primary key `id` that auto-increments (next to of course the columns storing the data). This is general-purpose configuration, so maybe there are more optimized ways given that I only need to write to the table, and not read from it?

Edit: I mainly fear that the website will go viral as soon as it's released, so I expect the users to visit in a very short timeframe. And of course I would not like to lose the data that they enter due to an overloaded database.

Comment: The **best** data structure for write-only data is nothing.  The next best would be a flat file ... that is, if you're really worried about writes holding up the processing.  I imagine that most of the time, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer - Isn't that what the MySQL BLACKHOLE storage engine is for? :)

Comment: It's not really for writing only, you need to read it to do statistical analysis.

Comment: What do you mean by flat file? If I read a file, add a line to it, and write it back, then the 100000th line will require 100000 lines to be read and written, no?

Comment: if you want to do statistical analysis you should collect the data from the server log... is there any data, that you might need, that is not on the server log?

Comment: Yes, it is the data that they enter. Gender, age, and answer to some personal psychological questions. This is not in the server logs. :)

Comment: From what you're describing (one row added each time a user enters something) MySQL will keep up with the app, even if it "goes viral". You can use it without worries. As for question #2, the structure should be adequate. Keep the `id` column because sooner or later you'll be in a position where you'll need it.

Comment: No, you can append to a file without reading and rewriting the entire thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is a perfectly reasonable choice for this. Probably much better than a flat file, since you say you want to aggregate and analyze this data later. Doing so with a flat file might take a long time, especially if the file is large. Additionally, RDBMS are for aggregation and dataset manipulation. Ideal for creating report data.

Put whatever data columns you want in your table, and some kind of identifier to track a user, in addition to your existing row key. IP address is a logical choice for user tracking, or a magic cookie value could potentially work. It's only a single table, you don't need to think too hard about it. You may want to add nonclustered indexes on columns you'll frequently filter on for reports, e.g. IP address, access date, etc.

> I mainly fear that the website will go viral as soon as it's released, so I expect the users to visit in a very short timeframe. And of course I would not like to lose the data that they enter due to an overloaded database.

RDBMS such as MySQL are explicitly designed to handle heavy loads, assuming appropriate hardware backing. Don't sweat it.

Comment: The report is made on my local computer, so that's not a problem, but OK, I'll stick to it then. Thanks! :)